# How do I install an application from a source code Zip file?

Tags: windows-10, installation, zip

I have been trying to install TaskbarX from the source code Zip file available here: https://chrisandriessen.nl/taskbarx to Windows 10 OS. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find an .exe file to install this app. As this is my first time installing an app to Windows from a zip file, I am not sure how to do it. Please do help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The source code does not contain an executable.  The source code is simply the programming code that *makes* the executable.  You would need to compile the code to create an executable file.  Source code is provided so that, if you had the programming ability and knowledge, see how the program works.  It also lets you modify the code, if you wanted to make a change to how the program works.

In your case, this is not the package you want.  You want to download a precompiled version that contains the executable.  The link to the Microsoft Store version or the portable versions (select the version for your hardware) on this [page](https://chrisandriessen.nl/taskbarx), is what you want.